# Does a second normal form normalization always lead to a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: database, normalization

Can you give me an example where it is the case and another where it's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd Normal form means eliminating Repeating groups. this would typically lead to Many to one relationships. 
eg. If you have a group of students registered for the course ISY23AT, you move the course into a different table.
Many to many relationships fall under 3rd Normal form.